# how to get the degree of two point so that i can rotate the image and show direction with custom annotation image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, mkmapview, mapbox-gl

I am able to retrieve the degree of two points and rotate the image with that degree. But in order to show the direction, sometimes i need to add 180 with the actual degree or sometime i don't have to add degree. Its because of the custom annotaion image i am using. Any kind of help help would be really appreciated.

```
- (double) getDirection
{

    //Determine the direction
    double lat1 = self.startCoOrdinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lon1 = self.startCoOrdinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lat2 = self.endCoOrdinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lon2 = self.endCoOrdinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;

    double dLon = lon2 - lon1;
    double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
    double radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);


    NSLog(@"degre between points is %f",(radiansBearing * 180.0) / M_PI);


    double degree = radiansBearing * 180.0 / M_PI;


    return (degree + 0);
}

- (UIImage*)rotatedImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage byDegreesFromNorth:(double)degrees {
    CGSize rotateSize =  sourceImage.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotateSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotateSize.width/2, rotateSize.height/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, ( degrees * M_PI/180.0 ) );
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                       CGRectMake(-rotateSize.width/2,-rotateSize.height/2,rotateSize.width, rotateSize.height),
                       sourceImage.CGImage);
    UIImage *rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return rotatedImage;
}
```